# Sharepoint online connection works, but Get-PnPFile fails to download a file

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Error:
Get-PnPFile: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Testing from my own laptop works fine
Testing from a server in our network connects fine, but errors out on attempting to download a file.

Ideas from previous searching -

- Verified .NET 4.8 is installed on the server in question (apparently
  4.7.2 is min required).
- Cipher suites do have 2 matching ciphers on both the server and Sharepoint.

If the connection works, but the download fails, I'm not sure what else to check.
The error implies Sharepoint itself is forcibly closing the connection, but I have no idea why.
Any ideas where to look next?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - the problem resolved itself today and I have no idea why.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).